# Spring make sure Bean properties have been set when using a no-args constructor

Tags: java, spring

When using a no args-constructor in Spring is it possible to make sure that some properties have been set before the bean is initialized? I want to use `InitializingBean` to validate settings after the bean has been created. E.g., what I want to do:

```
public class HelloWorld implements InitializingBean{
   private String message;

   public HelloWorld()
   {
      //Only no-args constructor must be used
      //How do we make sure 'message' was ever set before the Bean is used?
   }

   public void setMessage(String message){
      this.message  = message;
   }

   public void getMessage(){
      System.out.println("Your Message : " + message);
   }

   public void afterPropertiesSet(){
      //Validate object, requires message to be set!
   }
}

public class MainApp {
   public static void main(String[] args) {

      AbstractApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Beans.xml");

      //Bean is instantiated
      HelloWorld obj = (HelloWorld) context.getBean("helloWorld");
      //Bean is initialized and thus afterPropertiesSet() is called here. It will fail because it requires 'message' to be set.

      //Right after the bean is instantiated we set the 'message', but it's already to late. afterPropertiesSet() was already called.
      obj.setMessage("Hello World!");

   }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand. You have the `afterPropertiesSet`, just throw an exception or some other indicator that it hasn't been initialized correctly.

Comment: The message can be injected into that class, since the bean can't be created without its dependencies being injected (at least by default). The container is going to do the whole thing for you, basically.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis So how would you suggest to create the Bean in the given MainApp example? I can't call obj.setMessage before the bean is created using context.getBean which executes afterPropertiesSet() in the process of bean creation. The exception would always fire. I don't see how, in the given example, I can initialize the bean correctly.

Comment: @mszymborski can you show an example how you suggest the injection to work for the given example?

Comment: I assumed you set the property in your application context. If you don't then this is not possible: _that some properties have been set before the bean is initialized_ The bean is initialized before being made available to clients of the `AppplicationContext`.

Comment: @masi: <bean class="HelloWorld" name="helloWorld">
    <property name="message">
        <value>Hello World!</value>
    </property>
</bean> should do the trick

Comment: @mszymborski that's static at configuration time. What if message should be - as in the given example - configured dynamicly?

Comment: @masi: you can use FactoryBean, which will somehow figure out what to inject: http://howtodoinjava.com/spring/spring-core/how-to-create-beans-using-spring-factorybean/

Answer (score 0):

To inject things determined at runtime, please consider using FactoryBean. It's basically the Factory pattern, but supported by Spring natively:

```
    public class SomeWeirdMessageFactoryBean implements AbstractFactoryBean {
        public Class<?> getObjectType() {
            return String.class;
        }

        protected Object createInstance() throws Exception {
            String message;
            // magic:
            [...]
            return message;
        }
    }
```

The `magic` part is obviously what has to figure out what to return. You then have to inject it as property of your class, and Spring is going to figure out that it's a factory and do the dirty work for you.

Comment: Thanks for your replay but I don't see how this would help. The createInstance() method doesn't take any parameters and in the example from howtodoinjava.com you posted it's clear that the properties are still injected using pre-configured xml files. the factory will take an array of bean configurations and build multiple beans. it's yet not clear to me how to dynamicly provide a configuration in order for the properties to be set at run time before the bean is initialized. I guess I'm taking the wrong aproach here and will try to rethink the design itself.

Comment: @masi: could You please provide the use case you are looking for? createInstance can use any method you want to get the current configuration - fetch if from database, the network, a cache you provided. Of course if you don't want to hardcode it you would have to provide these as beans, too, in the factory's constructor, and initialize them later - the point is the parameter is calculated at the very moment you request the bean (asuming either `prototype` or lazy `singleton` scope)